# Javascript regular expression to validate annual income

Tags: regex

I would like to create a regular expression in javascript to validate the annual income of a user. The problem I have is with the comma symbol, since a comma should be followed by 3 digits.

If I use this regex: (\d{3,3}\,)* then 1,000 will not match since it expects a comma at the end.

While if I use this regex: [\d]+(\,\d{3,3})* 1000,000 will match and it is not correct since it should be 1,000,000

Any help would be appreciated.

Thx in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
^\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*$
```

BTW, I think it is better to allow the user enter any numbers they like, and then you add the commas at the appriopriate places.

Comment: @SeRPRo: It will be correct if you require it to match the whole string. (OK added ^$ anyway.)

Comment: @KennyTM Thx it works. However I don't understand this part: ?:,
Kindly could you explain pls?

Comment: @Spi1988: It is a [non-capturing group](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3512471/non-capturing-group). This is like `(...)` but does not generate captures (those `$1`, `$2` things)

Answer (score 0):

How about this one:

```
(?:[^,\d]|^)(\d{1,3}(?:,\d{3})*)(?:[^,\d]|$)
```